# Fundamental group of two circles joined by an arc

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the fundamental group of two circles joined by an arc? In other words, let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two standard circles. Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be two points in $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively. Join $p_1$ and $p_2$ by an arc $l$. Let $S$ be union of $S_1$, $S_2$ and $l$. What is the fundamental group of $S$?

Comment: What would you expect it to be?

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried, and any conjecture you might have. Also, do you know the fundamental group of the circle, and maybe a theorem that allows you to calculate the fg of a space expressed as the union of two simpler ones?

Answer (score 1):

Using Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem:

Let $M$ be the graph you described  two circles joined by an arc.

Choose points $x_1 \in S_1$ , $x_2 \in S_2$ and $x_1,x_2$ are not the intersection points of circle and arc.

It's easy to see $S_2$ is the deformation retract of $M-\{x_1\}:=M_1\Rightarrow \pi_1(M_1)=\mathbb Z$

And $S_1$ is the deformation retract of $M-\{x_2\}:=M_2 \Rightarrow \pi_1(M_2)=\mathbb Z$

Moreover, deformation retract of $M_1 \cap M_2$ is a single point $ \Rightarrow \pi_1(M_1 \cap M_2)=0$.

Hence , $\pi_1(M)=$ Free product of $\pi_1(M_1)$ and $\pi_1(M_2)$ = $\mathbb Z \ast \mathbb Z$, by Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem.